# Visual C++ - How to use resx with dot in name: texts.en-US.resx

Tags: .net, visual-c++, resx

TLDR

```
texts_en-US.resx --> texts_en-US.resources   <- included in dll
texts.en-US.resx --> texts.en-US.resources   <- not included in dll
```

I have an embedded resx called **texts.en-US.resx** in my C++ project. On build this file is correctly compiled to **texts.en-US.resources**, but it is not included in the dll. If I name it **texts_en-US.resx** it is correctly included.
How do I include **texts.en-US.resources** (with a dot in the filename) in the dll?

Further info
I want to use the [ResXResourceManager](https://github.com/dotnet/ResXResourceManager) that needs this dotted filenames to show all languages in one row. Or is it possible to configure it to recognize underscores like **texts_en-US.resx**? I couldn't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to adjust the ResXResourceManager to recognize also files like **texts_en-US.resx**: [ResXResourceManager with RegEx_based_file_detection](https://github.com/NJM-Goals/ResXResourceManager/tree/RegEx_based_file_detection)